# Trouble with calculations on new record

Tags: vba, ms-access, addition, edit, calculation

I have a program which holds bowling ball measurements and calculates oval thumbs & span corrections for inserts.  My only issue is when I attempt to add a new record using a macro (using "Openform" and "goto record...new").  This button works flawlessly until I enter a record using an oval thumb which requires calculations based on data in the form which returns a 3021 run time error.  Editing of current database records also works flawlessly.  The Debug gets hung at rs.edit under "calculate oval sin/cos" notation.

```
Private Sub Combo151_AfterUpdate()
    Call OvalCalc

End Sub

Private Sub OvalCalc()
    Me.Hole1.Value = Me.Combo151.Column(2)
    Me.Hole1f.Value = Me.Combo151.Column(1)
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim cutcount As Integer
    Dim Cut As Integer
    Dim CutnameH As String
    Dim CutnameV As String
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("select * FROM MeasureT Where CustomerID=" & Me.CustomerID)
    If OvalDegree <> 0 Then
    'Calculate Oval Sin/Cos
        Refresh
        rs.Edit                                 
        rs.Fields("OvalVert") = Hole1
        rs.Update
        rs.Edit
        rs.Fields("OvalDiff") = Round(OvalHoriz - OvalVert, 3)
        rs.Update
        rs.Edit
        rs.Fields("OvalSin") = Round([OvalDiff] * Sin([OvalDegree] * 1.74532925199433E-02), 3)
        rs.Fields("OvalCos") = Round([OvalDiff] * Cos([OvalDegree] * 1.74532925199433E-02), 3)
        rs.Update
        If OvalSin > OvalCos Then
            rs.Edit
            rs.Fields("OvalCuts") = Round(OvalSin / 0.036, 3)
```

My complete database is available for download at:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0n3PtRkzdg4UXNDZXg3QTFfeVk/view

MainMenuF (contains the name search & add new buttons)
When testing oval routine, values should be entered for the "OVAL THUMB" Horizontal (ex value: 1) & Degree (ex value: 35) Fields and the Forward/Reverse (ex value: .250) & Left/Right Pitches (ex value: .250) (above and to the right of the thumb hole).  Then upon entering a thumb size (combo151 afterupdate()) (ex value:  15/16) the program will calculate the Sin/Cos/Diff/Cuts and table movements to achieve the desired hole size.  Interestingly enough...if you end the debugger and re-enter the thumb size a 2nd time...it works flawlessly.  The cut to cut finger grip routine (also uses calculations based on table data) works perfectly as well even on a new record.  I am a Dbase III+ Programmer trying to learn & adapt to access...any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I know I'm missing something simple.  (side note:  Oval Compute button on form does not work properly)

*Update:  Not a complete fix but I found a workaround.  I have added a "save record" button which when pressed prior to adding a thumb size (which activates the oval routine if a degree has been entered) seems to take care of the issue.  I may be in error since I am a novice at access compared to dbase III...but I believe the record was not written and my routine was attempting to do calculations on a record which didn't exist.  Thus why the save record button was effective in creation of the record and allowing the oval routine to finish as planned.

Comment: So this is SQL in Access and not MySQL?

Comment: This is Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications within Access...yes.